# Hints wanted on scanning pictures from books

Tags: graphics

I am writing a book proposal in LaTeX.  It will have a lot of graphics, most of which I will create, and I know how to deal with those.  But I have gotten permission to reproduce some pictures from books.  I'm having trouble making good graphics.

I tried copying the page on a copier, then cutting out the part I need, then scanning that, then inserting that figure.  This is cumbersome, and the quality isn't good (I guess copying and then scanning each lose some quality).  I've been doing this on a standard desktop all-in-one printer.

Does anyone have a better method?

Comment: This seems off-topic to me: it's nothing to do with TeX at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scan the pages with a flatbed scanner. Any recent model will do. Make sure you use 24-bit color and save to a lossless file format such as PNG or TIFF. These are your *masters*. You can then retouch and save a separate compressed version.

[scantips](http://scantips.com)

Comment: When I have to add a picture, (if it's some graph) I scan it and make a new one in Illustrator (perfect for graphs). You can also use Photoshop for retouching...